# Jobs in PlayFramework 2.3.X

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I need to perform a background task on my PlayFramework 2.3.X server (check DB status and perform action dependind on this status). 
  
To do this, I saw Play used to use `Jobs` [(here)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/jobs) in its early version. I would like to do the same but wasn't able to figure out what is the new way to handle this. 
  
Ps: I know this is not a good thing to do so, but I have to perform this background task. If you find a better way, please feel free to let me know. 
  
Thanks!

**EDIT** 
I try something like this using Java Akka, but I miss a parameter. Any advice?

```
public static void test(){
        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule (
                Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),   // initial delay 
                Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES),        // run job every 5 minutes
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Logger.info("job is done");
                    }
                }; 
         ); 
}
```

Comment: I think Akka and its Scheduler will percect fit for you.

Comment: Yes, I try to use it right now, but I face some issues... I edited my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your jobs
    }
};


Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(FiniteDuration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS), FiniteDuration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), task, Akka.system().dispatcher());
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what `Akka.system().dispatcher()` is? Also, do I have something specific for this method to be executed?

Comment: Dispatcher is something like a conigutation for given Actor system...for more read: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html
If your task is not anything advance you can youse default dispatcher. 
They wrote in documentation that if you have more advance actors hierarchy it might speed up their work

Comment: I did what you told me and the method seems to work properly (without compilation bug). However, I don't find a way to "launch" the method at startup and then do an action every x minutes. Do you knwo what else i have to do?

Comment: In play you have a specific class called GlobalSettings.You can create your own class and override onStart method which run every time when you start your application...Just put your method which execute Akka.scheduler in side onStart metchod....That should solve the problem :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot :)